# What is the IsNested equivalent compact framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, equivalent

What could I use in replace of [IsNested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isnested.aspx) since it is not supported in the compact framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it using Reflector, looks like its this:

```
bool is_nested = (array_type.DeclaringType != null);
```